# Autocomplete match on contains instead startwith

Tags: vb.net, textbox, textchanged

I search how to use Autocomplete [contains instead of starting with] in winform TextBox but apparently no such result that I want appear.

So I try this code here , no error but it wont appear. Am I missing something?

```
Private Sub txtSelection_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSelection.TextChanged
        Dim suggestions As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        Dim str As String = txtSelection.Text
... 'get dtselection from mysql'
 For i As Integer = 0 To dtSelection.Rows.Count - 1
            If dtSelection.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString().ToLower.Contains(str.ToLower) Then
                suggestions.Add(dtSelection.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString())
            End If
        Next

        txtSelection.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        txtSelection.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txtSelection.AutoCompleteCustomSource = suggestions


    End Sub
```

Comment: There's a reason that there are no results when you search for that. It's because it can't be done. The inbuilt autocomplete functionality works the way it works. If you want something that works a different way then you need to build that yourself.

Comment: i try already in my code above to get the list of "suggestions" using loop if dtselection.contains.(txtselection). Is it still suppose not working. is there any suggestion for alternate ways?